# Is there a function that finds the OR of every row in a boolean matrix in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, boolean-logic

I have a matrix A of size n x m and all the entries are bools.  I want all my calculation to be on the GPU and I have matrix A stored as a tensor with each entry being the pytorch's bool datatype.  I want an output of a single vector, b, to be a 1 x m tensor that stores the OR of all rows in A.

What I want:
A matrix = 
[a<sub>1,1</sub>, a<sub>1,2</sub>, , a<sub>1,3</sub>, ... , a<sub>1,m</sub>]
[a<sub>2,1</sub>, a<sub>2,2</sub>, , a<sub>2,3</sub>, ... , a<sub>2,m</sub>]
...
[a<sub>n,1</sub>, a<sub>n,2</sub>, , a<sub>n,3</sub>, ... , a<sub>n,m</sub>]

b = [b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, , b<sub>3</sub>, , ..., b<sub>m</sub>]

s.t. b<sub>i</sub> = a<sub>1,i</sub> | a<sub>2,i</sub> | a<sub>3,i</sub> | ... | a<sub>n,i</sub>
where | is the OR operator in Pytorch

essentially I want a function that applies row or column wise boolean operation. I know the | `.__OR__` can be used and Pytorch's OR function takes two boolean tensor as inputs and I would need to loop over all rows to get my desired b vector.

Since OR is commutative (a|(b|c) = (a|b)|c), I would think pytorch would have some nice function that speeds it up by doing the | operations in parallel or in some divide and conquer method, instead of doing this with a loop. Any ideas or references to speed up the process of applying communicative row/column wise boolean operation with pytorch is welcomed.  Best if all operations are done on the GPU.

Comment: Can you share an example/test matrix?

Comment: @AMC an or truth table is a 2d case of what I'm trying to achieve, but the question was answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`torch.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html?highlight=torch%20any#torch.BoolTensor.any) and [`torch.all`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.BoolTensor.all).

Both take a `dim` argument and hence you can compute `or`/`and` of rows.

Comment: Thank you, I just started pytorch so I appreciate the help

Comment: Glad! we were of help. If you think this answer is sufficient, do accept it. That will help the future users who run into this problem :)